# Update failed error in my trigger

Tags: apex, after-trigger

## Trigger

```
trigger Account_AU on Account (before insert, before update, after insert, after update)
{

    if(AccountTriggers.toBeExecuted){
        if(Trigger.isBefore) {
            if(Trigger.isInsert) {
                AccountTriggers.setRecordType(Trigger.new, (new Map<Id, Account>()));
                AccountTriggers.updateAccFields(Trigger.new,(new Map<Id, Account>()),true);
                AccountTriggers.updateCustomerCategories(Trigger.new, null);
            } else if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
                AccountTriggers.setRecordType(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
                AccountTriggers.updateAccFields(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap,false);
            }
        } else if(Trigger.isAfter) {
            if(Trigger.isInsert) {
                AccountTriggers.PushGlobalCustomerDistributionTierToStores(Trigger.New);
                system.debug('inside insert');
                AccountTriggers.FlagContactsForAccountSharing(Trigger.New, null);
                if(!utility.IsAccountAfterInsertCalled){
                    utility.IsAccountAfterInsertCalled=true;
                    utility.IsAccountAfterUpdateCalled=true;
                    AccountLocationMappingtoStore.deepCloneAccountLocation(Trigger.new,trigger.oldMap,true);
                    AccountTriggers.deepCloneAccount(Trigger.new, (new Map<Id, Account>()));
                    AccountTriggers.CheckdeptAccount(Trigger.new);
                }
            } else if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
                AccountTriggers.FlagContactsForAccountSharing(Trigger.New, Trigger.oldMap);
                AccountTriggers.CheckdeptAccount(Trigger.new);
                AccountTriggers.managingCountry_Update(Trigger.New, Trigger.oldMap);
                if(!utility.IsAccountAfterupdateCalled){
                    utility.IsAccountAfterupdateCalled=true;
                    AccountTriggers.updateCustomerCategories(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Class

```
public with sharing class AccountTriggers{
    public static Boolean toBeExecuted = true;
    public static Map<String, Triggers__c> triggers = Triggers__c.getAll();
    public Static List<Account> accUpdatenewList=new List<Account>();
    public Static Set<Id> setAccountIds=new Set<Id>();

    public static Id masterCustomerRecordID = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Master Customer').getRecordTypeId();
    public static Id locationRecordID = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Location').getRecordTypeId();
    public static Id customerRecordID = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Customer').getRecordTypeId();
    public static Id hierarchyRecordID = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Hierarchy Node').getRecordTypeId();
    public static Map<Id, String> recordTypes = new Map<Id, String>{
        masterCustomerRecordID => 'Master',
        locationRecordID => 'Location',
        customerRecordID => 'Customer',
        hierarchyRecordID => 'Hierarchy'
    };

    static {
        system.debug(recordTypes);
    }

    public static Boolean shouldRun(String funcName) {
        String key = 'Account_'+funcName;
        system.debug(key);

        // First, search for master kill switch.  Use that, if it's there.
        if(triggers.get('Account_ALL')!=null) return Boolean.valueOf(triggers.get('Account_ALL').IsEnabled__c);
        system.debug(key);

        // If it's in the map, then return the value.
        if(triggers.get(key)!=null) return Boolean.valueOf(triggers.get(key).IsEnabled__c);
        system.debug(key);

        // If it's not in the map, then assume true.  (If they've built a trigger, we
        // assume they want it to run, unless specifically told otherwise)
        return true;
    }

    public static Map<String, Boolean> recordTypeRun = new Map<String, Boolean>();
    public static void setRecordType(List<Account> mNew, Map<Id, Account> mOld) {
        if(!shouldRun('SetRecordType')) return;
        system.debug('asdf');

        // Find all parent account ids for non-location accounts.
        Set<Id> parentAccountIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(Account acct: mNew) {
            if (
                acct.ParentId != null &&
                (acct.RecordTypeId == masterCustomerRecordID || acct.RecordTypeId == customerRecordID || acct.RecordTypeId == hierarchyRecordID)
            ) {
                parentAccountIds.add(acct.ParentId);
            }
        }
        Map<Id, Account> parentAccounts = new Map<Id, Account>();
        if(parentAccountIds.size()>0) parentAccounts = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, RecordTypeId FROM Account WHERE Id IN :parentAccountIds]);

        // Count children.
        Map<Id, Integer> childCountByParentId = new Map<Id, Integer>();
        if(mOld.size() > 0) {
            for(Account a: [SELECT Id, ParentId FROM Account WHERE ParentId IN :mOld.keySet()]) {
                Integer count = childCountByParentId.get(a.ParentId);
                if(count==null) count = 0;
                count++;
                childCountByParentId.put(a.ParentId, count);
            }
        }

        for(Account acct: mNew) {
            // Get a unique identifier for this account.  Name+(Generated|Id).
            String aid = acct.Name + '_' + (acct.Id == null ? String.valueOf(acct.System_Generated_Location__c) : acct.Id);

            if(recordTypeRun.containsKey(aid)){

                continue;
            }
            // Remember this aid, so we can avoid processing again in the future.
            recordTypeRun.put(aid, true);

            Account oldAcct = mOld.get(acct.Id);

            if ( recordTypes.keySet().contains(acct.RecordTypeId) ) {

                Id parentRecordTypeId = null;

                if(acct.ParentId!=null && parentAccounts.get(acct.ParentId)!=null) parentRecordTypeId = parentAccounts.get(acct.ParentId).RecordTypeId;

                Integer childCount = 0;
                if(acct.Id!=null && childCountByParentId.get(acct.Id)!=null) childCount = childCountByParentId.get(acct.Id);

                String debug = 'Record '+aid+' is one of our 4 types.  Evaluate what its type should be based on our criteria.\n';

                if ( String.isNotBlank(acct.SAPAccountNum__c) ) {

                    if (
                        acct.System_Generated_Location__c == false &&
                        acct.ParentId==null && acct.DSE__DS_Ultimate_Parent__c == null &&
                        (acct.Global_Store_Key__c==null||acct.Global_Store_Key__c=='')&&
                        ((acct.IsOwnerGroup__c == true &&( acct.Owner_Group_Number_Text__c == acct.SAPAccountNum__c ))||
                         ( acct.IsOwnerGroup__c==false && (acct.Owner_Group_Number_Text__c == null||acct.Owner_Group_Number_Text__c==''||acct.Owner_Group_Number_Text__c!=acct.SAPAccountNum__c) && acct.IsTopNode__c == true && acct.Top_Node_Number_Text__c == acct.SAPAccountNum__c  ) ||
                         ( acct.IsOwnerGroup__c == false && acct.IsShipTo__c==true && acct.IsSoldTo__c == true && acct.IsTopNode__c == false && acct.Sold_To_Number_Text__c == acct.SAPAccountNum__c )||
                         (acct.IsOwnerGroup__c==true && acct.IsShipTo__c==true && acct.IsSoldTo__c==true && acct.IsTopNode__c==true)
                        )
                    ) {
                        //  system.debug('RT: Master Customer, '+aid);
                        acct.RecordTypeId = masterCustomerRecordID;
                    }
                    else if ( acct.IsOwnerGroup__c==false&&// !IsOwnerGroup && !IsShipTo && Has Owner_Group_Number_Text => Hierarchy
                             (acct.Global_Store_Key__c==null||acct.Global_Store_Key__c=='')&&
                             acct.IsShipTo__c == false && acct.IsSoldTo__c==true &&
                             String.isNotBlank(acct.Owner_Group_Number_Text__c)
                            )
                    {
                        // system.debug('RT: Hierarchy, '+aid);
                        acct.RecordTypeId = hierarchyRecordID;
                    }

                    else if ((acct.IsShipTo__c==false && (acct.Global_Store_Key__c!=null||acct.Global_Store_Key__c!=''))||
                             (acct.IsShipTo__c==true&&(acct.IsOwnerGroup__c==false && acct.IsTopNode__c==false)||
                              ((acct.IsOwnerGroup__c==true||acct.IsOwnerGroup__c==false)&&(acct.ParentId!=null||acct.DSE__DS_Ultimate_Parent__c!=null)&&(acct.Global_Store_Key__c==null||acct.Global_Store_Key__c==''))))
                    {
                        // system.debug('RT: Location, '+aid);
                        acct.RecordTypeId = locationRecordID;
                    } else {
                        // system.debug('RT: Unchanged ('+acct.RecordTypeId+'), '+aid);
                    }
                }
                /*******endng record type assign********/
                /*  else {
                system.debug('No SAP#.  Leave it alone. '+aid);
                }*/
            }
            /*****Record type with in account finsished here*******/
            else {
                system.debug('RT NOT Customer, Master Customer, Location, or Hierarchy.  Leave it alone. '+aid);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void updateCustomerCategories(List<Account> accountList, Map<Id, Account> oldAccts) {
        map<string,Account> parentMap = new  map<string,Account>();
        map<string,list<Account>> childMap = new  map<string,list<Account>>();
        List<Account> updateAccount = new List<Account>();
        Account accRef=new Account();
        // if(!shouldRun('UpdateCustomerCategories')) return;


        Set<Id> accIds = new Set<Id>();
        Map<String,List<Account>> accInserIdMap = new  Map<String,List<Account>>();
        for(Account acc:accountList){

            Account oldAcct = null;
            if(oldAccts != null && oldAccts.get(acc.Id) != null) {
                oldAcct = oldAccts.get(acc.Id);
            }
            if(oldAcct != null){
                if(( oldAcct.Customer_Categories_for_MC__c != acc.Customer_Categories_for_MC__c )) {
                    parentMap.put(acc.id,acc);
                    accIds.add(acc.Id);
                    //if it is only one parent then updated account will be assigned to this account reference
                    accRef =  acc;
                }
            }
            //It is for Inserted records
            if(oldAcct == null  && acc.parentid != null && acc.IsSoldTo__c==true ){
                system.debug('insiode insert'+acc.parentid);
                if(accInserIdMap.containskey(acc.parentid)){ //need to check when it will work
                    accInserIdMap.get(acc.parentid).add(acc);
                }
                else{
                    accInserIdMap.put(acc.parentid,new List<Account>{acc});
                }
            }

            else if(oldAcct != null  && acc.parentid != null && acc.IsSoldTo__c==true ){
                system.debug('insiode update'+acc.parentid);
                if(accInserIdMap.containskey(acc.parentid)){ //need to check when it will work
                    accInserIdMap.get(acc.parentid).add(acc);
                }
                else{
                    system.debug('insiode update1'+acc.parentid);
                    accInserIdMap.put(acc.parentid,new List<Account>{acc});
                }
            }
        }
        system.debug(accInserIdMap+'accInserIdMap############');
        system.debug(accids+'accids############');
        //This loop only for inserted records.
        if(accInserIdMap.size() > 0){
            system.debug(accInserIdMap+'accInserIdMap############');
            List<Account> accList = [select Customer_Categories_for_MC__c,Customer_Category__c,Primary_Category_for_MC__c from Account where id in:accInserIdMap.keyset()];
            system.debug(accList+'accList############');
            Set<string> newCatSet = new Set<string>();
            if(accList.size() > 0){
                for(Account acc:accList){
                    for(Account accRefNew:accInserIdMap.get(acc.id)){
                        if(accRefNew.Customer_Categories_for_MC__c != null){
                            /******************changes on 5th******************/

                            if(accList.size() > 0){
                                if(accList[0].Customer_Category__c!=null && accList[0].Customer_Category__c.split(';').size()>0){
                                    Pattern nonAlphanumeric = Pattern.compile('[^a-zA-Z;\'/ ]');
                                    Matcher matcher = nonAlphanumeric.matcher(string.escapeSingleQuotes(accList[0].Customer_Category__c));
                                    string st =matcher.replaceAll('').trim().replace('; ', ';');
                                    for(String stCat: st.split(';')){
                                        newCatSet.add(stCat);
                                    }
                                }
                            }


                            if(accRefNew.Customer_Category__c!=null && accRefNew.Customer_Category__c.split(';').size()>0){
                                Pattern nonAlphanumeric = Pattern.compile('[^a-zA-Z;\'/ ]');
                                Matcher matcher = nonAlphanumeric.matcher(string.escapeSingleQuotes(accRefNew.Customer_Category__c));
                                string st =matcher.replaceAll('').trim().replace('; ', ';');
                                for(String stCat: st.split(';')){
                                    newCatSet.add(stCat);
                                }
                            }

                            system.debug('newCatSet'+newCatSet);
                            /******************changes on 5th******************/
                            /**************changes made now***********************/
                            Set<String> catSet = new Set<String>();
                            if(acc.Customer_Categories_for_MC__c!=null){
                                for(String stCat: acc.Customer_Categories_for_MC__c.split(';')){
                                    catSet.add(stCat);
                                }
                            }

                            for(String stCat: accRefNew.Customer_Categories_for_MC__c.split(';')){
                                catSet.add(stCat);
                            }

                            String custCategory = '';
                            String custCategoryMC = '';
                            Integer i=0;
                            for(String catValue : newCatSet){
                                i++;
                                custCategory += i+' '+catValue+';';

                            }
                            for(String catValue : catSet){

                                custCategoryMC += catValue+';';
                            }

                            custCategory= custCategory.substring(0,custCategory.length()-1);
                            custCategoryMC= custCategoryMC.substring(0,custCategoryMC.length()-1);


                            //custCategory.charAt(custCategory.length()-1) = '';

                            /**************changes made now***********************/

                            acc.Customer_Categories_for_MC__c = custCategoryMC;
                            acc.Primary_Category_for_MC__c = accRefNew.Primary_Category_for_MC__c;
                            acc.Customer_Category__c  = custCategory;

                            //acc.Customer_Category__c  = accRefNew.Customer_Category__c;

                        }
                    }

                }
                update accList;
                system.debug('accList'+accList);
            }
        }

        // The below loop will run for the update of the Account
        if(!accIds.isEmpty()){
            system.debug('inside account id'+accIds.size());
            if(accIds.size()==1){
                system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@hi'+accIds);
                getAllChildAccountIds(accIds);
                system.debug('accIds'+accIds);
                for(Account acc:accUpdatenewList){
                    system.debug('insode else lopp'+accRef.Customer_Categories_for_MC__c);
                    system.debug('insode else lopp'+accRef.Customer_Category__c);
                    if(accRef.Customer_Categories_for_MC__c != null){
                        system.debug('insode else lopp');
                        acc.Customer_Categories_for_MC__c = accRef.Customer_Categories_for_MC__c;
                        //  if(acc.inherit__c == true){
                        acc.Customer_Category__c = accRef.Customer_Category__c;
                        acc.Primary_Category_for_MC__c = accRef.Customer_Categories_for_MC__c.split(';')[0];
                        //  }
                        acc.IgnoreValidation__c = true;
                    }
                }
                system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@hiaccUpdatenewList'+accUpdatenewList);
                if(accUpdatenewList.size() > 0){
                    utility.IsAccountAfterupdateCalled=true;
                    update accUpdatenewList;
                }
            }

            else{
                Database.executeBatch(new Batch_CustomerCategoryUpdate(accIds), (Test.isRunningTest() ? accIds.size() : 1) );
            }


        }

        /* catch(Exception ex){
        System.debug('Cat Exception'+ex.getmessage());
        } */
    }


    // Return list of all child Account Ids
    public static void getAllChildAccountIds(set<Id> setAccId){
        Set<Id> tempIdSet=new Set<Id>();
        for(Account acc:[Select Id, name,Customer_Category__c, Synchronize__c,Customer_Categories_for_MC__c,inherit__c,Primary_Category_for_MC__c from Account where parentid in :setAccId]){

            accUpdatenewList.add(acc);
            tempIdSet.add(acc.id);

        }
        if(tempIdSet.size()>0){
            setAccountIds.addAll(tempIdSet);
            getAllChildAccountIds(tempIdSet);
        }
    }


    public static void updateAccFields(List<Account> accountList, Map<Id, Account> oldAccts,boolean check){
        Id locationRecordID = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Location').getRecordTypeId();
        List<account> accUpdateList = new List<account>();

        //Following else loop will only run for the update of Account
        if(oldAccts != null&&check==false){
            Map<string,Account> soldToAccMap = new Map<string,Account>();
            Map<string,Account> soldToAccMap1 = new Map<string,Account>();
            Map<string,Account> sapAccNumberMap = new Map<string,Account>();

            for(Account acc:accountList){

                if(acc.SAPAccountNum__c==null && acc.IsSoldTo__c==false && locationRecordID==acc.RecordTypeId&&( acc.CustomerDistributionTier__c != oldAccts.get(acc.id).CustomerDistributionTier__c || acc.Managing_Country__c != oldAccts.get(acc.id).Managing_Country__c ||acc.Lead_Category__c!=oldAccts.get(acc.id).Lead_Category__c||
                                                                                                                acc.SalesOrg__c != oldAccts.get(acc.id).SalesOrg__c||acc.Account_Class__c != oldAccts.get(acc.id).Account_Class__c || acc.Channel_Class_Name__c != oldAccts.get(acc.id).Channel_Class_Name__c||acc.customer_Category__c!=oldAccts.get(acc.id).customer_Category__c)){

                                                                                                                    soldToAccMap.put(acc.id,acc);
                                                                                                                    soldToAccMap1.put(acc.Sold_to__c,acc);

                                                                                                                    if(acc.SAPAccountNum__c != null && acc.SAPAccountNum__c!=''){
                                                                                                                        sapAccNumberMap.put(acc.SAPAccountNum__c,acc);
                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                }
            }
            if(soldToAccMap.size() > 0 ){

                set<string> soldTo=soldToAccMap.keyset();
                set<string> soldTo1=soldToAccMap1.keyset();
                set<string> sapSet= new set<string>();

                string query = 'select id,Sold_to__c,Customer_Category__c,Lead_Category__c,Sold_To_Number_Text__c,GBHGeo__c,GBHTerritory__c, CountryCode__c,SalesOrg__c,CustomerDistributionTier__c,SAPAccountNum__c,Channel_Class_Name__c,Managing_Country__c,Account_Class__c from account where ID in:soldTo1';

                if(sapAccNumberMap.size() > 0){
                    sapSet=sapAccNumberMap.keyset();
                    //query = query+' or Sold_To_Number_Text__c in:sapSet';
                }

                for(Account accRef:(List<Account>)Database.query(query)){

                    if(accRef.Sold_to__c != null){

                        Account acc = new Account(id = accRef.id);
                        acc.CustomerDistributionTier__c = accRef.CustomerDistributionTier__c;
                        acc.Channel_Class_Name__c = accRef.Channel_Class_Name__c;
                        // if(acc.Managing_Country__c == null){
                        acc.Managing_Country__c   =  accRef.Managing_Country__c;
                        //}
                        acc.Account_Class__c      =  accRef.Account_Class__c;
                        acc.SalesOrg__c=accRef.SalesOrg__c;
                        acc.Lead_Category__c=accRef.Lead_Category__c;
                        acc.Customer_Category__c=accRef.Customer_Category__c;
                        accUpdateList.add(acc);
                    }

                    if(accRef.Sold_To_Number_Text__c != '' && accRef.Sold_to__c == null){

                        Account acc = new Account(id = accRef.id);
                        acc.CustomerDistributionTier__c = accRef.CustomerDistributionTier__c;
                        acc.Channel_Class_Name__c = accRef.Channel_Class_Name__c;
                        acc.Managing_Country__c   = accRef.Managing_Country__c;
                        acc.SalesOrg__c=accRef.SalesOrg__c;
                        acc.Account_Class__c      =  accRef.Account_Class__c;
                        acc.Lead_Category__c=accRef.Lead_Category__c;
                        acc.Customer_Category__c=accRef.Customer_Category__c;
                        // if(acc.Managing_Country__c == null){

                        // }

                        accUpdateList.add(acc);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        if(accUpdateList.size() > 0){
            utility.IsAccountAfterUpdateCalled=true;
            Update accUpdateList;
        }

        //Following else loop will only run for the insert of Account
        else{
            set<id> soldToAcc = new set<id>();

            set<string> sapAccNumber = new set<string>();
            for(account acc:accountList){

                if(acc.recordTypeId == locationRecordID ){
                    if(acc.Sold_to__c != null){
                        soldToAcc.add(acc.Sold_to__c);
                    }
                    if(acc.Sold_to__c == null && acc.Sold_To_Number_Text__c != ''){
                        sapAccNumber.add(acc.Sold_To_Number_Text__c);
                    }
                }

            }
            if(!soldToAcc.isEmpty() || !sapAccNumber.isEmpty()){
                Map<string,account> accMap = new Map<string,account>();

                string query = 'select id,Account_Class__c,Customer_Category__c,Lead_Category__c,CustomerDistributionTier__c,GBHGeo__c,GBHTerritory__c,CountryCode__c,SalesOrg__c,SAPAccountNum__c,Channel_Class_Name__c,Managing_Country__c from account where';
                if(!soldToAcc.isEmpty() &&  !sapAccNumber.isEmpty()){
                    query = query+' id in:soldToAcc';
                }

                if(!soldToAcc.isEmpty() &&  sapAccNumber.isEmpty()){
                    query = query+' id in:soldToAcc';
                }

                if(soldToAcc.isEmpty() &&  !sapAccNumber.isEmpty()){
                    query = query+' SAPAccountNum__c in:soldToAcc';
                }
                for(Account accVal:(List<Account>)Database.query(query)){

                    /*if(!soldToAcc.isEmpty()){
                        if(soldToAcc.contains(accVal.id)){
                            accMap.put(accVal.id,accVal);
                        }
                    }

                    if(!sapAccNumber.isEmpty()){
                        if(sapAccNumber.contains(accVal.SAPAccountNum__c)){
                            accMap.put(accVal.SAPAccountNum__c,accVal);
                        }
                    }
                if(accMap.size() > 0){*/
                    for(account acc:accountList){

                        //***********If Sold to value is part of location record ***********
                        if(soldToAcc.contains(acc.Sold_to__c)){

                            acc.CustomerDistributionTier__c = accVal.CustomerDistributionTier__c;
                            acc.Channel_Class_Name__c = accVal.Channel_Class_Name__c;
                            // if(acc.Managing_Country__c == null){
                            acc.Managing_Country__c   =  accVal.Managing_Country__c;
                            //}
                            acc.SalesOrg__c=accval.SalesOrg__c;
                            acc.Account_Class__c      =  accVal.Account_Class__c;
                            acc.Lead_Category__c=accVal.Lead_Category__c;
                            acc.Customer_Category__c=accVal.Customer_Category__c;

                        }

                        //*********** If only Sold_To_Number_Text__c value is part of location record ***********
                        if(sapAccNumber.contains(acc.Sold_To_Number_Text__c)){

                            acc.CustomerDistributionTier__c = accVal.CustomerDistributionTier__c;
                            acc.Channel_Class_Name__c = accVal.Channel_Class_Name__c;
                            // if(acc.Managing_Country__c == null){
                            acc.Managing_Country__c   =  accVal.Managing_Country__c;
                            //  }
                            acc.SalesOrg__c=accVal.SalesOrg__c;
                            acc.Account_Class__c      =  accVal.Account_Class__c;
                            acc.Lead_Category__c=accVal.Lead_Category__c;
                            acc.Customer_Category__c=accVal.Customer_Category__c;
                        }
                    }

                    // }
                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 001U000001Qffa9IAB; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, Account_AU: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 001U000000Vm9lbIAB; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, Account_AU: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 001U000000Vm9lbIAB; first error: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER, Object (id = 001U000000Vm9lb) is currently in trigger Account_AU, therefore it cannot recursively update itself: [] Class.AccountTriggers.updateAccFields: line 755, column 1 Trigger.Account_AU: line 22, column 1: [] Class.AccountTriggers.updateCustomerCategories: line 585, column 1 Trigger.Account_AU: line 54, column 1: []

Comment: Please put more efforts in formatting the question content so that someone can understand the issue and help you ASAP.

Comment: if i add my code, the formatting is not coming properly. i am getting copied the code like this only.

Answer (score 1):

Error:

> first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, Account_AU:
>   execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed

**Solution:-** 
You need to put recursive check so that your trigger should execute only one time.

```
// Class to check recursion
 public Class checkRecursion{

    private static boolean run = true;
    public static boolean runOnce(){
      if(run){
       run=false;
       return true;
      }else{
        return run;
      }
    }
}
```

Use this class in your trigger like following:-

```
trigger triggerName on YourSobject (trigger events) {
     if(checkRecursion.runOnce())
       {
       //write your code here           
       }

    }
```

Ref: [Avoid Recursive Trigger Calls](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000133752&language=en_US&type=1)

More explanation for your question in comment section regarding Before trigger:-

> Nachiket, i think in my code i am doing update operatioj for before
>   update on updateaccfields method. i think tat is wrong. can u tell me
>   can we do update in before trigger

**You can not do DML Operation for the Sobject you are using in your before trigger, if you do so you will recive a runtime error.**

```
trigger YourTrigger on Sobject (before trigger events) {
    `if(Trigger.isBefore){
        if(Trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isinsert){
            list<Sobject> sobjectlist = new list<Sobject>();
            for(Sobject obj : trigger.new){
                 obj.customfield__c = 'Value On Before Trigger'; //Its correct as No DML operation involved
                 sobjectlist.add(obj);     
            }
        }
    }
    Update sobjectlist;// This is incorrect, you can do this by sending list in future method.
}
```

Comment: Nachiket, i think in my code i am doing update operatioj for before update on updateaccfields method. i think tat is wrong. can u tell me can we do update in before trigger

Comment: @VinothiniMurugesh I have updated my answer, hope this helps you, let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Thank you. I think this will help me. My code has update in before update . The same account update i am doing it in After update also. So it was throwing error. i have commented out the update opeartion which has done in before update. so that my error is not populating now